# Does adding linearly dependent columns to a totally unimodular matrix preserve total unimodilarity?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, integer-programming, total-unimodularity

I was wondering the following. Given a totally unimodular matrix $A$ and a vector $b \in Im(A)$ is then the matrix $[A,b]$ totally unimodular too? My guess is no, since for total unimodilarity every subdeterminant has to be +1,-1 or 0 and the subvector $b'$ extracted from $b$ might not be linearly independent with the columns of the submatrix $A'$ of $A$, but I was unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: Total unimodularity requires that all entries are $\pm 1$ or $0.$ The added vector must be of that form.